# How to load fish command history from file

Tags: fish

Is there a way to load commands-history of fish from a file?

I like to clear my history periodically, but keep a set of useful commands always in history for easily accessing.

In bash this can be done via:

```
history -r file.txt
```

Can this be done in fish?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience what you want to do isn't really necessary since a) fish only remembers the most recent instance of a command and b) generally does a really good job of using available context to provide the most appropriate entry from the command history, and c) already trims old entries once the number of saved commands reaches a limit.

But, assuming you've saved your preferred history subset to `~/.local/share/fish/fish_history.save`:

```
builtin history clear
cp ~/.local/share/fish/fish_history.save ~/.local/share/fish/fish_history
history merge
```

The `builtin` in the first instance is to avoid the prompt asking if you really want to clear your history. Note that your saved history has to be valid YAML. It's a text file but is a little more complex than just each command on a separate line.